# Hyperbolic analog to sinx = cos(pi/2 - x)

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

Is there a hyperbolic analog to that? I understand the circular trigonometric relation comes from analysing a right-angled triangle in Euclidean space, but how can we visualise the analog in hyperbolic space?

Comment: More correctly, circular functions $(\cos t,\sin t)$ arise as coordinates of the point on the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ subtending a sector of area $t/2$. Analogously, hyperbolic functions $(\cosh t, \sinh t)$ arise as coordinates of the point on the unit hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$ subtending a sector of area $t/2$. The "sector" in the circular case is bound by the positive $x$-axis, the circle, and the ray from the origin through the point. The "sector" in the hyperbolic case is bound by the positive $x$-axis, the hyperbola, and the ray from the origin through the point.

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle-\,\mathrm{i}\sinh\left(\mathrm{i}x\right) = \cosh\left(\mathrm{i}\left[{\pi \over 2} - x\right]\right)$. Set
$\displaystyle z = \,\mathrm{i}x \implies
\bbox[15px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{ \sinh\left(z\right) =\,\mathrm{i}\cosh\left(z - {\pi \over 2}\,\mathrm{i}\right)}$

Comment: Hi, thanks for showing the relation; but geometrically how can I interpret this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,but not exactly like that.

$$\sinh x = e^x - \cosh x$$